# Double X Axis in Plotly plot for one line

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a plot in python using Plotly that allows me to add 2 x axis to a single plot. I just tried but every single tutorial and documentation add a second trace to the plot with y and x data, but if you do that it will generate a second line and I just want a line that represents both axis. I mean de mainly x axis will be the bottom one and the secondary can be the upper one. The plot will be generated using y and x data (from the mainly x axis).

I already have this, but as you can see is not very clear...
[image]

```
fig = go.Figure()

for percentile, color in zip(percentiles_m, colors_m):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                y=curves_df[percentile],
                x=[curves_df.index, remaining_patients],
                name=percentile + "th",
                mode="lines+markers",
                textposition="top center",
                line=dict(color=color),
            )
        )

fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Remaining patients/Repetition", tickangle=0, tickfont=dict(size=11), dividerwidth=1)

fig.update_yaxes(title_text=feature_selected, tickfont=dict(size=11))
```

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, you can use `x=[tuple(main_x),tuple(sub_x)]` to set main `xaxis` and sub `xaxis`. Please refer below code:

```
fig_1 = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Bar(x=[tuple(df['Season']), 
                  tuple(df['category_name'])],
               y=list(df['sale_dollars'])),
    ])
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I just edited my post, because I already used that solution but for me it is a bit confusing the results. I would like to see a bit separately from each other and have different axis names instead of just a name

Comment: Can you post your work? I think we need to see how did you do.

Comment: I already posted! Thanks